# Как отцентровать текст в двустрочном div?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

Делаю таблицу на `div`, требуется отображать данные в 2 строки.

Делаю так:

```
div {
    height: 3em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Но в некоторых ячейках текста только на 1-ну строчку.

Как отцентровать текст по вертикали, при сохранении двухстрочных `div`?

Answer (score 2):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  max-height: 3em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  width: 9em;
}
```

```html
<div>Однострочый</div>
<div>Многострочный. Многострочный.</div>
<div>Overflow работает. Overflow работает. Overflow работает.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  outline: 1px dotted red;
  width: 9em;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
}

span, div:before {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

span {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div><span>Однострочый</span></div>
<div><span>Многострочный. Многострочный.</span></div>
<div><span>Overflow работает. Overflow работает. Overflow работает.</span></div>

<hr>

<div><span>Только не сломай. Правый уполз вниз.</span></div>
<div>
  <span>Только не сломай. Правый уполз вниз.</span>
</div>
```